# If I study Kabbalah at a place called Kabbalah Centre am I jewish?

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah

I come from a christian background and I've been always interested in learning more about where it came from. After sometime however I've been participating in the sabbath and tithing which is quite new to me and I don't feel that the connection everybody has when reading the torah in Hebrew and its prayers (mostly because I don't understand it). If sabbath gives a person energy to last a week, is it selfish that I asked for it and where does the energy come into play? If I also tithe, I know the 10% was going to be taken regardless but I have the ability to put it in a good place (Centre or not) instead of it being taken from my assets that I own if I used the tithe to buy something with it. I recently had an expense that I owe that will take most of my funds, do I still try to tithe the 10%?

Comment: The content of the question does not match the title of the question.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Mi Yodeya.  It's not clear what you're asking (sabbath, tithes, kabbalah, personal status?).  I'm closing this question to allow you to [edit](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/25843/edit) in some clarification.  When you've done that, please ping me in a comment (@MonicaCellio) so I can reopen.  You might have more than one question here; if so it'll work better if you ask them separately.  Thanks.

Comment: @Monica, I think we should try and clear this question up so as to get answers which could warn people about this very real issue.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt do you mean having a question about the status of the Kabbalah Center?  That seems valuable; I wonder if it's best done by asking a new question that's more clear.  Asking and answering your own question is completely kosher, by the way, so if you're able to answer that, please feel free to do that.  Or maybe bring it up on meta or in chat to get help?

Answer (score 6):

You are asking various questions in the body of the text which is unrelated to your title question: If I study Kabbalah at a place called Kabbalah Centre am I jewish?

To start with that question, only through conversion can one become Jewish. Conversion is a long process that eventually requires commitment to following Jewish law (called halakha), circumcision (for men), and immersion in a kosher mikveh (ritual bath). More information can be found [here](http://www.judaismconversion.org/). Attending and/or participating in any organization does not equate to being Jewish.

I question the premise of your other questions. The laws of the Sabbath and tithing are explicitly for Jews to follow, and so I don't see the applicability of the questions you asked.

Finally, I think it should be noted that the Kabbalah Center has been seriously frowned upon by many Jewish authorities (I don't think there is a single authority from traditional/orthodox Judaism that approves of the organization). There are many deeply ethical problems the Center commits - from the financial (tax evasion and excessive profitting of religious and pseudo-religious ("holy" water, red strings) merchandise) to the much more serious violations of misrepresenting Judaism by exploiting Jewish mysticism. For more information on why the Kabbalah Center does not represent Judaism, see [The Truth about the Kabbalah Center](http://freedomofmind.com/Info/TheTruthAbouttheKabbalahCentre.php) and the [Jewish Introduction on learning Kabbalah](http://www.aish.com/ci/ss/Learning_Kabbalah.html) for starters.

Comment: Could you write a new version of this answer or migrate it, for a new version of this question? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/52552/is-the-kabbalah-center-kosher?noredirect=1#comment138083_52552