# Is the Kabbalah Center kosher?

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, chinuch-education

I suspect many have heard of the Kabbalah Center. Founded by Philip Berg (who went by the moniker of R' Yehudah Berg, despite likely lacking semicha), the Kabbalah center is known for publishing editions of the Zohar, translations thereof, a kabbalistic siddur with translated kavanot, and numerous completely original works by Berg and his followers.

However, The Center has also, according to Wikipedia, been plagued by many financial scandals and also teaches their kabbalah to non-Jews, a practice which I have heard is forbidden. They also practice theurgy (practical kabbalah) and may encourage ideas of shituf.

Considering this, is the Kabbalah Center a legitimate Jewish institution of learning?

Comment: wasn't there a question on this site about this, which had an answer of someone's personal experience with it?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/25843/759

Comment: @DoubleAA, this is an attempt to revitalise the question with per discussion with Monica Cellio on Bam.

Comment: @DoubleAA that question asks a bunch of things, unclearly, by a user who isn't around to clarify any more.  I suggested to Noach that it would be better to ask a new question specifically about the Kabbalah Center, not entangled with the other stuff in that question.

Comment: Ask them to explain to you a hard tosfos in zevachim or a hard Rashba...