# Who are Simon/Sperling/Levertoff the translators of the Soncino Zohar?

Tags: translation, zohar, publications

I am looking for an English Zohar and found this:

https://soncino.com/products/the-soncino-zohar

It lists the translators - however I could not find anything about these people online.

My goal is to vet the authors and thereby not be influenced by liberalizations of the text.

Comment: I have no information on Simon or Sperling, but Levertoff is.... problematic. https://seforimblog.com/2019/01/another-obvious-mistake-more-grammatical-points-bubbe-mayseh-apostates-and-the-zohar/

Comment: There are three widely available translations of the Zohar in English- the one done by the Kabbalah Center, the Socino one, and the
Pritzker Edition, which is an academic translation. The last one is almost certainly the least pagummed

Comment: An article from the 30s https://www.jta.org/archive/first-english-translation-of-zohar mentions the full names of Harry Sperling and Maurice Simon. That might help you in finding more information.

Comment: @יהושעק, The Kabbalah Center is definitely problematic, based on other threads on this forum

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt ABSOLUTELY. But Levertoff was a leading 'scholar' of the Jews-for-baal Nittlenacht movement (yishmach shmo) as explained in the link I put in the comments

Comment: @יהושעק, I know, I read the link. I don't think that clears Berg, whose ideas are also heretical and border on עבודה זרה. See the question linked to my question here https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/52552/is-the-kabbalah-center-kosher and I would further expand that if one needs a translation of the Zohar, they probably aren't ready for the text, which is easy to misinterpret in a heretical manner

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt one form of keffira doesn't clear the other, both translations are highly problematic. The academic one is, too, but in a less problematic way ;)